# Organizing Laravel Controllers Folders

Tags: php, symfony, laravel, laravel-4

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'admin'), function()
{

    Route::group(array('before' => 'admin-auth'), function()
    {
Route::get('/add-draft', array('as' => 'admin-get-draft', 'uses' => 'Vendor\Controllers\Admin\CrawlController@viewDraft'));
Route::post('/add-draft', array('as' => 'admin-post-draft', 'uses' => 'Vendor\Controllers\Admin\CrawlController@addDraft'));
    });

});
```

Composer

```
"autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "Vendor": "app"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "app/commands",
            "app/controllers",
            "app/models",
            "app/database/migrations",
            "app/database/seeds",
            "app/tests/TestCase.php"

        ]
    },
```

CrawlController

```
<?php namespace Vendor\Controllers\Admin;
class CrawlController extends BaseController{
```

I'm getting

```
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException
Class 'Vendor\Controllers\Admin\User' not found
```

Inside my Controller , I have a admin Folder which contains controller(CrawlController.php)

I want to be able to use ORM , which would call my Model folder which is at the same level as the controllers folder.

How can i do it properly with PSR-0? The above are my codes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your controller is loading properly, but it's looking for a User class inside the same namespace.  Chances are you're trying to load your user model in your controller.  You have to either declare the user model using a USE statement after your namespace declaration, or prefix your classes with a "\" like "\User"

Comment: How do i properly declare the user model ?

Comment: The user model is technically in the global namespace so \User.  However you don't need to actually namespace your controllers.